# Produce Avro messages in Confluent Control Center UI

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-control-center

To develop a data transfer application I need first define a key/value avro schemas. The producer application is not developed yet till define the avro schema.

I cloned a topic and its key/value avro schemas that are already working and
and also cloned the the jdbc snink connector. Simply I just changed the topic and connector names.

Then I copied and existing message successfully sent sink using Confluent Topic Message UI Producer.
[image]

But it is sending the error: "Unknown magic byte!"

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.getByteBuffer(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:250)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.<init>(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:323)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:164)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(AvroConverter.java:172)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:107)
        ... 17 more
[2022-07-25 03:45:42,385] INFO Stopping task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask)
```

Reading other questions it seems the message has to be serialized using the schema.

[Unknown magic byte with kafka-avro-console-consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399417/unknown-magic-byte-with-kafka-avro-console-consumer)

is it possible to send a message to a topic with AVRO key/value schemas using the Confluent Topic UI?

Any idea if the avro schemas need information depending on the connector/source? or if namespace depends on the topic name?

This is my key schema. And the topic's name is knov_03

```
{
  "connect.name": "dbserv1.MY_DB_SCHEMA.ps_sap_incoming.Key",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id_sap_incoming",
      "type": "long"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Key",
  "namespace": "dbserv1.MY_DB_SCHEMA.ps_sap_incoming",
  "type": "record"
}
```

[image]

Connector:

```
{
  "name": "knov_05",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "topics": "knov_03",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://eXXXXX:3306/MY_DB_SCHEMA?useSSL=FALSE&nullCatalogMeansCurrent=true",
    "connection.user": "USER",
    "connection.password": "PASSWORD",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "delete.enabled": "true",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "id_sap_incoming",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "auto.evolve": "true",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081"
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how the UI knows you've tried to produce Avro... Maybe it thinks it is just JSON? Is there a particular reason you are wanting to use a UI instead of `kafka-avro-console-producer`??

Comment: I was not aware of kafka-avro-console-producer cli, it seems the tool I need to validate the schema. The messages produced in the UI looks json only.

Comment: If you use the UI to produce, then use regular `kafka-console-consumer` then what output format do you see?

Comment: It just seem a regular free text

Comment: Guess that answers the question then. Related thread - https://forum.confluent.io/t/control-center-produce-a-new-message-to-this-topic-breaks-with-avro/2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the current version of Confluent Control Center, it does not support sending messages in Avro format directly through its UI. The Control Center is primarily designed for managing and monitoring your Kafka environment.

For producing Avro messages, you would typically use other tools provided by Confluent, such as the Confluent REST Proxy or the Kafka Avro Console Producer. Both of these tools allow you to send Avro messages to Kafka, but they require that your Avro schema is registered with the Confluent Schema Registry.